# How to check programmatically if Azure app service plan supports P1V3 tier

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Due to latest changes in Azure premium tiers pricing we would like to migrate all existing app service plans to a new P1V3. There are certain plans that support the option, meaning if I open a service plan in Azure portal the P1V3 plan is available and I can change the tier.
[image]

But for certain plans, ones that were created long time ago the option P1V3 is not available
[image]

My question is if it's possible to fetch programmatically by using either az cli or Az PS module all plans that doesn't support the P1V3 option out of the box.

**Note**:
All app service plans that I need to scale up are deployed in geographical locations returned by

```
az appservice list-locations --sku P1V3
```

Answer (score 0):

The **PremiumV3** is available in some Azure regions and availability in additional regions is being added continually. To see if it's available in your region, run the following Azure CLI command

```
az appservice list-locations --sku P1V3
```

After confirmation from a region availability use below command to update the app service plan

```
az appservice plan update --name MyAppServicePlan --resource-group MyResourceGroup --sku P1V3
```

If the premium V3 is not available in your app deployed region you need to follow the below steps

You have two options:

1. Create an app in a new resource group and with a new App Service plan. When creating the App Service plan, select a **PremiumV3**    tier. This step ensures that the App Service plan is deployed into a    deployment unit that supports **PremiumV3**. Then, redeploy your    application code into the newly created app. Even if you scale the    App Service plan down to a lower tier to save costs, you can always    scale back up to **PremiumV3** because the deployment unit supports it.
2. If your app already runs in an existing **Premium** tier, then you
   can clone your app with all app settings, connection strings, and
   deployment configuration into a new resource group on a new app    service plan that uses **PremiumV3**.

[image]

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-from-an-unsupported-resource-group-and-region-combination)

Comment: Please see my Note

Comment: We tried our end it is working. Could you please raise a support ticket [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/)

Comment: I am not saying it's not working, I am just saying I need to get it programmatically. Followinig your steps works perfectly fine but it's a manual approach which doesn't scales for doesns of instances.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I don't think there is any **supported CLI/Powershell/REST API/script command** to confirm Premium V3 supported or not. However if its new deployment it can start from premium tier so that shouldn't be facing this issue.

The Premium V3 supportability depends on azure data center scale unit management. This scenario documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-from-an-unsupported-resource-group-and-region-combination